# View only visible after setOnClickListener action

Tags: android

I have a question concerning the behaviour of the visibility of a view.
I have a fragment and I am testing the visibility of a BottomNavigationView.

I have created a method to make the BottomNavigationView visible. It is as default not visible.

The method is:

```
public void ponerBut(){
        BottomNavigationView but = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        but.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I am calling the method from inside onCreateView from the fragment, as follows:

```
BottomNavigationView but = ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.navigation);
                but.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ponerBut();
```

If I call the method as it is from onCreateView, the BottomNavigationView is not visible.

But if I call the method from inside an onClickListener, then it works and the view is visible.

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ponerBut();
                    }
                });
```

I would appreciate an explanation for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this method in onActivityCreated() method of fragment.

```
ponerBut();
```